# Leave ear-speaker active when using headset (cable/bt)

Tags: audio, microphone, speaker, headset

Is it possible to *just* use a headset's mic but keep the phone's ear-speaker active?

Comment: Welcome to android.stackexchange.com. Usually the jack tells the phone to direct the sound to it only. Can you specify the device you have (brand and model)?

Comment: Thanks zuul. The phone is a _Samsung Galaxy Nexus_ but i hope there is a OS-dependent solution, rather than phone-specific hacks.

Comment: You can refer to this recent [answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/26122/16265) to a similar issue. Basically: *If a wired headset is plugged into the phone, it replaces the phone's built-in earpiece.*

Answer (score 1):

After some further research I think it's not possible.
At least on a level where one is not modifying the OS.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely not possible, the audio routing is something of a mutually exclusive/flip-flop principle.

If the headset is plugged in, the routing goes to the headset and is taken away from the in-built ear-piece. Vice-versa, if no headset is plugged in, the in-built-ear piece is used.

Likewise, for when during in-call without headset, audio routing goes to both ear-piece and mouth-piece, no other mp3/music cannot be played. For vice-versa, when no calls are happening, audio is routed to the speakers...

That shows what is actually involved in, what is known as "Audio routing" and is very complicated process hence the emphasis on mutual exclusivity/flip-flip operations of the audio fundamentals.